# Firebase create RTDB object if property name is uid

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

My data is

```
{
"users":{
}
}
```

Inside users I want to create

```
"varUID:{
"key":"any"
}
```

I want to set real time DB rule such that only users with auth.uid == the property name, eg: "varUID" can write it.

How to set a rule for it ?

"$uid": { ".write": "auth.uid === $uid" } helps to create data inside $UID, not for creating $UID. I want to create $UID

Comment: The same can be found in [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security#section-authorization)

Comment: "$uid": {
                ".write": "auth.uid === $uid"
            } helps to create data inside $UID, not for creating $UID. I want to create $UID

Comment: Yes that looks correct :D